# Efficient insertion of row into sorted DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

My problem requires the incremental addition of rows into a sorted `DataFrame` (with a `DateTimeIndex`), but I'm currently unable to find an efficient way to do this. There doesn't seem to be any concept of an "insort".

I've tried appending the row and resorting in place, and I've also tried getting the insertion point with `searchsorted` and slicing and concatenating to create a new `DataFrame`. Both being "too slow".

Is Pandas just not suited to jobs where you don't have all the data at once and instead get your data incrementally?

Solutions I've tried:

Concatenation

```
def insert_data(df, data, index):
    insertion_index = df.index.searchsorted(index)
    new_df = pandas.concat([df[:insertion_index], pandas.DataFrame(data, index=[index]), df[insertion_index:]])
    return new_df, insertion_index
```

Resorting

```
def insert_data(df, data, index):
    new_df = df.append(pandas.DataFrame(data, index=[index]))
    new_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
    return new_df
```

Comment: Perhaps use an sqlite table with an index to handle the updates? Then read that table with pandas when you need to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pandas` is built on `numpy`.  numpy arrays are fixed sized objects.  While there are numpy append and insert functions, in practice they construct new arrays from the old and new data.

There are 2 practical approaches to incrementally defining these arrays:

- initialize a large empty array, and fill in values incrementally
- incrementally create a Python list (or dictionary), and create the array from the completed list.

Appending to a Python list is a common and fast task.  There is also a list insert, but it is slower.  For sorted inserts there are specialized Python structures (e.g. `bisect`).

Pandas may have added functions to deal with common creation scenarios.  But unless it has coded something special in C it is unlikely to be faster than a more basic Python structure.

Even if you have to use Pandas features at various points along the incremental build, it might best to create a new DataFrame on the fly from the underlying Python structure.